# Android linkedin application issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two question regarding the android linkedin application

1. **I wants to close the linkedin login page when click back button after sharing some contents from my application**

   I was shared my content through linkedin share activiy, it's working fine if linkedIn is already **LOGGEDIN**. But, if i logout the linkedin then tried to share some contents login page will appear at this time i have tried to close the linkedin login page with clicking of back button. But Login page always showing it's does't closing.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

   ComponentName shareItem = new ComponentName("com.linkedin.android", com.linkedin.android.home.UpdateStatusActivity);    
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _myContent);
   intent.setComponent(shareItem);
   ```
2. **I wants to find the whether linkenin application is logged in or not.**

Answer (score 1):

> I wants to close the linkedin login page when click back button after
>   sharing some contents from my application

As to access any page/screen of linkedin app you need to be logged in so it's must to login first.

> I wants to find the whether linkedin application is logged in or not.

AFAIK not possible, as linkedin doesn't provide such info in any means.

Comment: Ok thanks for your replay.. Is there any possible way to kill linkedin app when clicks back button from login page.

Comment: I assume that there won't be any normal way to kill other application from your application, actually there is no need to kill it, android will do it when necessary..you just press back if you don't want to go further..